# Can it be called "criterion"?

Tags: word-usage

Can we call some rituals or some traditional actions of aboriginals a **criterion** they do?

For example:

> The native here pass their clothes to their child as a legacy, though this **criterion** is fading.

(please let me know if I made any grammar mistakes or some strange usage in this article, so I can improve my English)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A criterion is a *requirement*. Criteria is the plural. For example, you can say:

> There are three criteria for obtaining this job: you must have a degree, you must pass a skills test, and you must be enthusiastic about our company!

That means that the three things listed are requirements to get the job; you must have them or you will not get it.

So *criterion* doesn't make much sense in your sentence. There's two parts to criterion; 1) that it's required and 2) that it's required *in order for something else to happen* (ex. to get the job). You can stretch to assume the first one; that it's required that the clothes get passed down. But it's not required *in order for anything else to happen*. So it just doesn't make sense.

I think the word you're looking for is *tradition*, defined here at [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tradition) (emphasis mine):

> ***tradition***, noun
>
> 1) The *passing down of elements of a culture from generation to generation*, especially by oral communication.
>
> 2)
>
> a) A mode of thought or behavior followed by a people continuously from generation to generation; a custom or usage.
>
> b) A set of such customs and usages viewed as a coherent body of precedents influencing the present: followed family tradition in dress and manners. See Synonyms at [heritage](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/heritage).
>
> 4) A time-honored practice or set of such practices.

---

To answer your comment: no, *aspect* doesn't make sense here either. An aspect is a facet or a side of something; on part of the whole. You could call it an *aspect of their tradition*, though:

> The natives here pass their clothes to their child as a legacy, though this **aspect of their tradition** is fading.

This basically means "this part of their culture/the things they do" is fading.

Comment: Could **aspect** be used here?

Comment: For me, it is a custom. Neither criterion nor aspect really fit.

Comment: @rogermue Custom is a good word too! In this context, I think its meaning is similar enough to *tradition* that they're interchangeable.

Comment: +1 Specifically, a criterion is something required to earn a positive *judgment* or *evaluation*.